# How can i make a color transparent in node editor

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

I have these renderlayers:
[image]
[image]

In compositor I subtracted the second renderlayer from the first one (or used the difference node, since in this case they result to the same image)
[image]

But where the cube is, is now black (of course, since this is where the cube is, in both renderlayers). Is it possible to make transparent only where it's black on the image, so not object related, but just regarding the color of the pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the object index mask and the alpha over node to make the object transparent in the node editor.

Set object index:
[image: Object index]

Add the object index render pass:
[image: Object index render pass]

Node setup:

[image: Node setup]

Comment: Thank, but is it possible to make transparent only where it's black on the image, so not object related, but just regarding the color of the pixel?

Comment: Sure, behind the scenes the id mask node generates a black and white image, where the object is black and the rest if white. You can put any grayscale image into the alpha over node's factor input, and it will work in a similar fashion.

Comment: How do I enable IndexOB? Because after I set the object index mask, I don't see it

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that! edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly object index and ID mask exactly do? Like can I also make brown colors transparent?

Comment: I tried explaining this several times in text, but eventually decided this is better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CcOBLmvJAs

Comment: Or actually... this is better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuafulRKybs